# wpf : Always on top of parent window but keep parent window available

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, clickable

I'm developping a notification window for my application.
This notification is a window which popup at the bottom right of my main window.
To keep the notification on the top of my main window, I set the notification owner:

```
this.Owner = mainWindow;
```

But my problem is that my main window is now unclickable.
Do you know how to solve this problem.

EDIT :

I'm using .Net 4.0

My XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="ProjectTest.Resources.NotificationsWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxt="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v12.2"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:ProjectTest.Properties"
    Title="NotificationsWindow"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    x:Name="me"
    WindowStyle="None" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    SizeToContent="Height"
    MinHeight="120"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Closing="me_Closing"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
    Height="120"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=ThemeName}"
    Background="{DynamicResource {dxt:FloatingContainerThemeKey ResourceKey=FloatingContainerBackground, ThemeName=MetropolisDark}}"
    FlowDirection="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=FlowDirection, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Width="240"
    MouseMove="me_MouseMove">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Unloaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="boardUnloaded" Completed="boardUnloaded_Completed">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="me" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="boardLoaded">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="me" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="/ProjectTest;component/Assets/ContextMenu/Delete.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16" Margin="4"
               MouseUp="Image_MouseUp" Cursor="Hand"/>
            <Label x:Name="MessageTextBlock"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My C# :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Core;
using System.Windows.Threading;


namespace ProjectTest.Resources
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NotificationsWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NotificationsWindow : Window
    {
        Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        int countTimer = 10;
        int defaultTimer;

        public NotificationsWindow(int timer, string message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageTextBlock.Content = message;
            defaultTimer = timer;
            countTimer = defaultTimer;

            this.Owner = mainWindow;
            mainWindow.Focus();

            Loaded += (o, e) =>
            {
                mainWindow.LocationChanged += mainWindow_LocationChanged;
                mainWindow.SizeChanged += mainWindow_SizeChanged;

                UpdatePosition();

                DispatcherTimer DispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                DispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

                DispatcherTimer.Tick += delegate
                {
                    countTimer--;
                    if (countTimer < 0)
                        CloseNotification();
                };

                DispatcherTimer.Start();
            };
        }

        public static void Show(int timer, string message)
        {
            var window = new NotificationsWindow(timer, message);
            window.ShowDialog();
        }

        void mainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePosition();
        }

        void mainWindow_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePosition();
        }

        private void UpdatePosition()
        {
            if (PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) == null)
                return;
            try
            {
                var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
                var MainWindowPosition = mainWindow.GetPosition();

                var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(MainWindowPosition.X + mainWindow.Width, MainWindowPosition.Y + mainWindow.Height));

                this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth - 10;
                this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight - 10;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        bool FinalClose = false;
        private void Image_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            FinalClose = true;
            CloseNotification();
        }

        public void CloseNotification()
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private bool closeStoryBoardCompleted = false;

        private void me_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (countTimer > 0 && !FinalClose)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            if (!closeStoryBoardCompleted)
            {
                boardUnloaded.Begin();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }

        private void boardUnloaded_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainWindow.Focus();
            closeStoryBoardCompleted = true;
            this.Close();

        }

        private void me_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalClose)
                return;

            boardUnloaded.Seek(new TimeSpan());
            boardUnloaded.Stop();
            countTimer = defaultTimer;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I just want the notification to stay on top. The notification is a small rectangle, its like a Tooltip balloon. I want my main window to be available and to keep the notification visible even if the main window is in use.

Comment: why don't you make the notification a part of the main window then on a higher layer than the rest of the UI and just toggle it's visibility?

Comment: Because I found it easier to manage notification using a different window. I can call a static method like:
`Notification.Show("Message");`
By this way I can display notifications from any classes.

Comment: are you showing the notification window with a `.ShowDialog()`? If so switch it to a `.Show()` and try the same

Comment: I'm showing the notification with a .Show()

Comment: which .net version are you using can you put a sample together that shows this cos I can't reproduce this. Just setting owner as another window does not make the parent window un-clickable for me.

Comment: in the code you've posted you're calling `window.ShowDialog();` (you been lying to me? :P) from within `public static void Show(int timer, string message)` function.

Comment: Hem... That's awkward... Sorry, my bad...

Comment: Not directly related but if you want to launch multiple different form classes  on top of the main parent and maintain the original opening timeline of events then omit the owner property altogether. This way each child window opened by the parent will stay opened on top of the parent. Only hidden when interacting with the parent window but will remain activated but lost focus when interacting with other child windows opened by the parent. Inconsistent use of the owner property results in weird and erratic behavior on child windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my previous comment to an answer.

> are you showing the notification window with a .ShowDialog()? If so switch it to a .Show() and try the same

Just setting the `Owner` property of a `Window` does not make it modal. It's the `ShowDialog()` that does that part.